# slf4j + log4j shows all logs except mine

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using slf4j with log4j, and for some reason all the logs are showing except the logs that I write in my code - Spring logs, Hibernate logs, you name it logs are showing and in the level configured in log4j.properties. My logs however, are not showing.

Maven dependencies: 
    
        log4j
        log4j
        1.2.17
        test

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When running with `-Dlog4j.debug` I see that my log4j.propertes file is being used

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11a5ee7c.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11a5ee7c class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11a5ee7c.
log4j: Using URL [ile:/C:/x/y/myProject/target/test-classes/log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/C:/x/y/myProject/target/test-classes/log4j.properties
```

And I'm using the following log code:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
LOG.warn("Very informative message");
```

My log4j.properties file:

```
# Define the root logger to the system property "hbase.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshhold=ALL

#
# console appender
# Add "console" to rootLogger above if you want to use this
#
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %C{2}(%L): %m%n
```

Adding a specific line for my logger doesn't help as well

```
log4j.logger.com.my.path=DEBUG, console
```

And I can see that it is being recognized:

```
Parsing for [com.my.path] with value=[DEBUG, console].
log4j: Level token is [DEBUG].
log4j: Category com.my.path set to DEBUG
```

But still nothing is being logged.

Comment: do you have log4j.xml also, please post

Comment: no, only log4j.properites, never needed both properties and xml files together.

Comment: can you try adding `log4j.appender.console=DEBUG,org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`

Comment: After adding I'm getting `log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "console".`

Comment: try commenting out `log4j.appender.console.target=System.out`

Comment: I've added more information - the file is being parsed and the specific class also, but still nothing is showed.

Comment: @ankur-singhal tried commenting it out, still no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66717/discussion-between-ankur-singhal-and-apines).

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console
```

with this:

```
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, Console
```

Delete these two lines:

```
log4j.threshhold=ALL
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
```

Not sure what all of that pattern is doing, so I would replace this line

```
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%t] %C{2}(%L): %m%n
```

with this:

```
log4j.appender.Console.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Then do this:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClassName.class);
logger.info("This is info");
```